# How to call specific image after importing all images from a folder in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to import all icons from an icon folder and then find the specific icon and display it on the screen. I have imported all the icons with the below code:

```
const images = this.importAll(require.context('./icons', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
console.log(images);

importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the console log
[imported all images][1]

Now If I want to find a specific icon so how should I find it the name of the image file is not clear as highlighted in the screenshot.

```
const found = images.find(element => element = 'r04d.png');
console.log(found)
```

the above code output is shown below:

[output of found][2]

the name of the image file is not clear, how should I refer to this file and use it when required, please advise.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc1ff.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbZbt.png

Comment: I don't think find should be const found = images.find(element => element = 'r04d.png'); try  element == 'r04d.png' as it should return element if condition is true and you don't have condition in your code

Comment: Thanks @metamorph_online for your suggestion, I tried element == 'r04d.png' and element === 'r04d.png' it says 'undefined' when I console the output. Where I need to have a condition in my code, can you suggest?